# Mount "Windows" part of hybrid ISO in OS X (10.9.5)

Tags: mount, iso

I have an old hybrid ISO, WAR2BNE (Warcraft II: Battle.net Edition) in fact, that I am trying and failing to mount. The problem with the auto-mounting is that it uses the Mac portion and I need access to the Windows files.

A few web searches came up with various solutions, usually years old, that no longer work when attempted:

- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080708145453136
- http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-development-darwin/233131-mounting-windows-side-hybridized-cd.html
- http://loonsoft.com/post/2762643736/mount-iso-images-in-osx

I'm not afraid of the Terminal, I'm just not sure where to start researching to solve this.

Comment: can Disk Utility see it & possibly mount it?

Comment: ever found how to do this? I'm having the same problem now.

Comment: @Tetsujin -- Disk Utility sees devices and this is a file

Comment: @TheOddler -- No, I tried using `mount_cd9660` after attaching a pseudo-device with `hdiutil attach` (see wisbucky's answer below) but no go. My thought is that `hdiutil attach` only grabs the Mac partition

Comment: I'm struggling to think what my train of thought was 3.5 years ago ;-) but I'd be tempted to say 'just burn it to disk', then see wisbucky's idea.

Comment: @Tetsujin -- Yes, that's not a bad idea. Then my next step is to go buy some disks!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me to mount the Windows files in a hybrid CDROM. You should be able to do something similar for an ISO.

- Run `mount` to list the currently mounted disks. Find the one for the disk you are interested in. E.g. `/dev/disk2s1s2`
- Create a new directory under `/Volumes`, e.g. `/Volumes/win`
- Mount to the new directory with `sudo mount_cd9660 -er /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/win`. 9660 is the windows CD format, ISO 9660. Pay close attention to the device name, it is not the same as what is listed for `mount`. There is only one `s`, you truncate the extra `s`. So instead of `/dev/disk2s1s2`, you just use `/dev/disk2s1`.
- Now when you go to `/Volumes/win`, it should have the Windows files, not the Mac files.

Comment: This sounds great except `mount_cd9660` uses a device and not a file. Perhaps there is a way to mount the ISO as a device rather than a drive and then use these instructions?

Comment: I used `hdiutil attach filename.iso -nomount -readonly` to create `/dev/disk3s2` but when I run `sudo mount_cd9660 -er /dev/disk3s2 /Volumes/win` I get the error *Invalid argument*

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo mount_cd9660 -er /dev/diskx /mountpoint
```

where x is the disk number and mountpoint is any directory

Comment: The source is an ISO *file* not an actual device and the `mount_cd9660` command doesn't appear to support this.